# Contextual links for a custom module

Tags: 7, blocks, navigation

I want to add in a contextual link to a block.

The block shows up in different pages, not just a specific page.

Here is my current setup

```
$block['content'] =array(
    '#markup' => _get_markup(),
    '#attached' => array(
        'css' => array(
            drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/css/main.css',
        ),
        'js' => array(
            drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/main.js'
        ),
    ),
    '#contextual_links' => array(
        'add content' => array('add/content/', array('content')),
    ),
);
```

Based on the documentation, this should work for drupal 7 but it does not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I ended up using. By no means, this is the definite answer to my question. Although the code below accomplishes what is being asked I would *HIGHLY* discourage anyone from using it unless you have to.

```
function hook_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
    if($variables['links']['block-configure']['href'] === 'admin/structure/block/manage/BLOCKNAME/configure'){
        $variables['links']['custom_name'] = array(
            'title' => 'TITLE',
            'href' => 'path/to/node'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add your custom contextual link, you first need to check the Contextual links module is enabled. Even though you define everything correctly, it would not show, if it is disabled. Also, you need to set context to MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE in your menu items.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function example_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'my_custom_block':
      $block['subject'] = t('Example Block');
      $block['content'] = array(
      '#markup' => _get_markup(),
      '#contextual_links' => array(
          'add content' => array('add', array('node')),
      ));
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function example_menu() {
    $items['add/%/content'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add Content',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
        'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,
        'page callback' => 'contextual_node_page',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    // To use local task menu items, there must be a parent page.
    $items['add'] = array(
        'title' => 'Contextual Link Page',
        'page callback' => 'contextual_node_page',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}
```

#### Additional resources

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/administering-drupal-7-site/working-with-contextual-links
- http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-add-contextual-links-anything

Comment: The thing that i'm having a hard time understanding is the menu part. This block can technically live anywhere, why is there a fixed path, also there is several components that change this think "views" without the module "Contextual links". I found a weird hackish way to get through this but I just don't feel like its right.